# Editable (including Insert) Data Source which is Displayed Over Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, .net, crud

I have a Web App (C#) requirement where a user needs insert, update, cancel edit and delete (CRUD) capabilities on a set of data.  One record of the data source has to be displayed over two (or three) rows due to the quantity of fields.  GridView does not seem to be able to provide the capability of spanning one row; DataList does not have an insert capability.  An expandable GridView example I found did not have editable content.  I have tried multiple ways to achieve this requirement with multiple types of controls without success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGrid should give you what you need.  You can use TemplateColumns to define the way that a given cell is rendered on the page.

This link gives you the info you need.  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

If this does not give you enough flexibility then the DataRepeater control will give you full control that will allow you to render your own grid.